# Insufficient authentication scopes error for Google Sheet API for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to fetch a Google Sheet with the Google Sheets API for iOS. I've successfully added the user authentication since it's no longer asking for an API key, but I'm now getting a 403 error for:

```
Request had insufficient authentication scopes*.
```

I've added the following scopes in the Google Developers Console.

```
/auth/drive
/auth/spreadsheets
```

And here's the code I'm using to make and execute the query.

```
let potentialShowSheetID = "1n4wvD2vSSiAnG_pnD9rWR6dNCSnZz0pAGAiSYRaJCKs"
let service = GTLRSheetsService()
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets]  // This was specified in 
    // another Stack Overflow question, but I'm not sure how it would be used
    // and it doesn't seem to help.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: potentialShowSheetID)

    service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, data, error) in
        print("GTLRService ticket: \(ticket)")
        if error != nil {
            print("GTLRService potential show query error: \(error!)")
        }
        else {
            print("data: \(data ?? "unknown data")")

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to specify the scope in the query with the Google Sheets API for iOS? I looked through the framework pretty well and it doesn't ever seem to take that as a parameter. Maybe I'm missing something else.

**UPDATE**: I checked the granted scopes for the user and it doesn't include the Drive or Sheets API.

```
print("Scopes:", GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.grantedScopes ?? "unknown scopes")

    // Prints -> Scopes: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email]
```

How can I specify the scopes to grant access to during authentication?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around the Google Sign In API headers, I found I just had to specify the scopes with this:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets, kGTLRAuthScopeCalendar]
```

...before signing in with `GIDSignInButton`.